# Safari renders text in SVG with a different font

Tags: svg, safari, mobile-safari

I’m working with an SVG on a website, and everything works fine except in Safari. Safari displays my SVG with a completely different font than what I used for the graphic.

[Correct Rendering](https://mattyoungdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/img_0547.jpg)

This is how it’s supposed to display.

[Safari Rendering](https://mattyoungdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/img_0552.jpg)

This is how Safari renders it.

I don’t have a lot of experience with using SVGs in web design, but I’m using CSS to set it as a background-image like I would anything. I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong.

```
.titleContainer{
  background-image: url(‘../img/logo.svg’)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely because you should "convert to outline" when you export the SVG from your design program. I could imagine that you selected to embed the font.

Ie in Adobe Illustrator you have the option to outline the font when you export:

[Adobe Illustrator example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrDDB.png)

Comment: Or if you are using Inkscape for your SVG creation, select the text object (with the desired font on it) and use menu option: **Path > Object to Path**